# Sharepoint Online Redirect Is it possible to redirect subsite to another site?

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Sharepoint Online Redirect

Is it possible to redirect subsite to another site ?

From
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/Subsite/SitePages/Home.aspx

To
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/suzhou/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if any oob way to do it.

But i can tell you solution which will solve your problem.
You just have to add custom javascript to https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/Subsite/SitePages/Home.aspx

as below:

$(document).ready(function(){

window.location.replace("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/suzhou/default.aspx");

});

Hope this help you. :)

Comment: Hello ! I try to add this script on the script editor webpart however it doesnt worked :( I am write to put this script to the script editor?

Comment: yes. you also have to reference jquery file in your page html:

Comment: Sorry for bumping this old thread, but why wait for the DOM to load? It's better to do the redirect as soon as possible.